# JS function to return boolean if file exists

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to create a function in JavaScript this simply returns a true|false for the existence of a file on a web server using fetch().

I have the following code:

```
let tf = checkFile("index.html");
console.log("typeof(tf) = " + typeof(tf));

async function checkFile(file) {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(file);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not OK");
            
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I run it, it spits this out to the browser console:

```
"typeof(tf) = object"
```

Why doesn't it just return true or false?

Comment: It's an `async` function so it returns a Promise, and you're not waiting for the Promise to finish.

Comment: You may want to read about the [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) request method which allows you to check for a file without triggering a download.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the `typeof()` function from your console.log print

And also `await` for the response. Here you can read more about it
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp

You might need to invoke the `checkFile` function in a async function as well.

Try this

```
let tf = await checkFile("index.html");
console.log(`typeof(tf) = ${tf}`);

async function checkFile(file) {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(file);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not OK");
            
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```